# reCAPTCHA with node.js and express

Tags: node.js, express, recaptcha

Building an app with node.js and express and want to implement reCAPTCHA.
My code is the following:

```
const app = require('express')();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var request = require('request-promise');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))


app.post('/jow', (req, res, next) => {

  console.log(req.body['g-recaptcha-response']);

  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
    body: {
      secret: '6LcAuUoUAAAAAH-uiWl9cz0Wicg7iUsDxHImrgLO',
      response: req.body['g-recaptcha-response'],
    },
    json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
  };

  request(options)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('error');
    })

});
```

I get the following output when I verify the CAPTCHA and send the form:

[image]

The errors state that I have a missing input response (while I have the token as we can see logged out) and a missing input secret. This indicates that something went wrong in the http request send using the `request-promise` package. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

I know it's been a long time since the question, but, for future references, here's the solution.

The problem is with the **body** key:

```
  body: {
    secret: RECAPTCHA_SECRET,
    response: req.body['g-recaptcha-response']
  },
```

When using *request-promise* module and *recaptcha*, you should use the **form** key instead.

```
  form: {
    secret: RECAPTCHA_SECRET,
    response: req.body['g-recaptcha-response']
  },
```

Reference: https://github.com/request/request-promise#post-like-html-forms-do

Comment: Generally its best when you add a link to copy the relevant code into your answer. Still leave the link though but just expand your answer

Comment: Do you mean somethng like this? I've edited the answer formatting.